# How to display button text in textfield?

Tags: c#, oop, calculator

I have ten buttons with values from 0 to 9; i.e. calculator buttons.

**Goal:**

If I click the first button it will display **0** on the `textbox`.

I want to code this in as short as possible without coding inside the button click function.

Here's my related code:

```
        private Main main;

        public CalculatorClass calculatorClass = new CalculatorClass();

        private List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

        public Calculator(Main main)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.main = main;
        }

        private void Calculator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x >= buttons.Count; x++)
            {
                txtNumPad.Text = buttons[x].Click; //not working!
            }
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            main.EnableButton();
            this.Dispose();
        }
```

Also, I don't want to do like this:

```
btnZero.Text = "";
btnOne.Text = "";
btnTwo.Text = "";
btnThree.Text = ""; ...and so on


txtNumPad.Text = btnZero.Text;
```

Comment: So you want a button to react on clicking without using the the buttonClicked-function? Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Instead of double clicking each buttons (makes my code so long). I just want to do this in as short as possible.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to assign the same click function to all of your buttons:

```
foreach (var btn in buttons)
{
    btn.Click += btn_Click;
}
```

and then in the click event, you don't care which button was fired, because it was a button and you want to add it's text:

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn != null)
    {
        txtNumPad.Text = txtNumPad.Text + btn.Text;
    }
}
```

but without using a click function you will not be able to get your button react on a click.

Comment: It's something related to buttons with image. For example, I have ten buttons with different images and two checkboxes with change and unchange label. When I check the 'change', all 10 buttons will get similar images else it will return their original image. I want to do this using for loop so I could make my code short.

Comment: Is this now another question ? I don't get it at all sorry.

Comment: No. I just give example. Ignore if not helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

its not clear what you are trying to do 
but you can try **button[x].Text**, or be brief on what you want to do so that i can help

Comment: It's something related to buttons with image. For example, I have ten buttons with different images and two checkboxes with change and unchange label. When I check the 'change', all 10 buttons will get similar images else it will return their original image. I want to do this using for loop so I could make my code short.

Comment: then why dont you try image property of the button
for instance button[x].Image = "your image url" ;

Comment: No. What I want to do for now is to assign values or text for all the buttons on my form without making my code long. And if possible, I want to loop this.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void Calculator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
             Button btn = new Button();
             btn.Click += Program_Click;
             btn.Text = i.ToString();
             buttons.Add(btn);
         }
    }

    void Program_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNumPad.Text = txtNumPad.Text + ((Button)sender).Text;
    }
```

Comment: i have given  you and idea, now you have to implement that accordingly.